# Wrapper script to run native ld if cross ld fails

Tags: bash, gcc, ld, toolchain

I'm using cross-toolchain based on GCC and GNU binutils in automatic build system (Open Build Service).

There is a wrapper script that is located in place of usual binary `ld`. It calls cross `ld` instead of native `ld`.

But during the build of gcc-4.9 the following build error appears:

`ld: ./gcc/liblto_plugin.so: error loading plugin: ./gcc/liblto_plugin.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

So there is an idea to write the following wrapper for the cross `ld`, used during the build:

`#!/bin/bash
exec -a /usr/bin/ld.cross "$@" 2>/dev/null || exec /usr/bin/qemu-arm /usr/bin/ld "$@"`

There are 2 questions:

1. Does `ld` write anything to `stdin` (not `stderr`) in case of failure? Can this method cause wrong behaviour of `ld`?
2. Can this method be used for other cross executables:

   - as
   - nm
   - ranlib
   - ar
     ?

EDIT:

Above version does not work, the following one is better:

`#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/ld.cross "$@" || /usr/bin/qemu-arm /usr/bin/ld "$@"`

Comment: why `exec`, and why throw away std-err? why not `/usr/bin/ld.cross "$@" || /usr/bin/qemu-arm/usr/bin/ld "$@"` ? Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, @shelter, after some testing I have also noticed that version with `exec` does not work. And created a script that is similiar to yours.

Comment: Or, you could just fix the LTO problem (or not use -fLTO).